# Would this design of interface be considered bad?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I have written an `interface` for storing data as `List`/`Map` and have the ability to retrieve it back. Something like this:

```
public interface Repository {

    <K, V> void register(String typeTag, Key<K> key, V value);

    void unregister(String typeTag);
    void unregister(String... typeTags);
    void unregister(Collection<String> typeTags);

    <T> void add(String typeTag, T object);
    <T> void add(String typeTag, Collection<T> object);

    <T, K> T get(String typeTag, Key<K> key);
    <T, U, K> Map<T, U> getAsMap(String typeTag, Collection<Key<K>> keys);
    <T, U> Map<T, U> getAsMap(String typeTag);
    <T, K> List<T> getAsList(String typeTag, Collection<Key<K>> keys);
    <T> List<T> getAsList(String typeTag);
    <T, K> Map<String, T> get(Collection<String> typeTags, Collection<Key<K>> keys);

    <T> T remove(String typeTag, T object);

    void clear(String typeTag);
    void clear();

    <U, V> Map<U, V> map(String typeTag1, String typeTag2) throws IllegalMappingException;
    <U, V, K> Map<U, V> map(String typeTag1, String typeTag2, Collection<Key<K>> keys) throws IllegalMappingException;
    <U, V> Map<U, V> map(String typeTag1, Criteria<U> type1Criteria, String typeTag2, Criteria<V> type2Criteria) throws IllegalMappingException;
}
```

Now, I have well thought up the purpose of this interface and that can be defined through basically the following methods:

`register()`, `unregister()`, `add()`, `get()`, `remove()`, `clear()` and `map()`

But, as you can see there are overloaded versions of these methods that support taking and giving back data in `Collection`s. These can be classified as "convenience" methods(as it seemed to me). But it makes me wonder that the implementor is going to have to implement these methods as compulsion and there are just too many of these to implement. I personally got the feeling that the design is putting too much onto the interface and the "burden" should be reduced somewhat.

First of all,

**Is this design really bad?**

What things/strategy should I *take into consideration/apply* and keeping what in mind to change this design before I continue to expand the hierarchy.

**EDIT:**

I am only looking for solution in Java 7 and less.

Comment: For working code, codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask. To a certain degree :-)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an excellent use case for `default` interface methods. They basically allow you to implement these convenience methods in terms of the other methods in the interface.

For instance in the case of `add`:

```
<T> void add(String typeTag, T object); // defined by user

default <T> void add(String typeTag, Collection<T> object) {
    for(T t : object) {
        add(typeTag, t);
    }
}
```

However, if the user wants to implement a default method (for instance because they can give a more optimal implementation), they *can* still override a `default` method.

---

Edit: For per-Java8 you could create an `abstract` class that implements the convenience methods, and have that serve as a template for user classes to extend. Although that is a less optimal solution since it forces the user to extend a class, and you can only extend 1 class.

```
abstract class AbstractRepository implements Repository {

    ...

    @Override
    public <T> void add(String typeTag, Collection<T> objects) {
        for(T t : objects) {
            add(typeTag, t);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

...

```
class RepositoryImpl extends AbstractRepository {
    ...
}
```

Comment: But they were introduced in Java 8. I was thinking of some solution in Java 7 and less. Is there something for Java 7? I shall reflect this in my question as a requirement.

Comment: @pulp_fiction Alternatively, you could create an `abstract` class with these convenience methods already implemented, and have users extend that class. But it's a less optimal solution, since it forces the user to extend a class, and you can only extend 1 class.